# Load a single file at a time or all files at once into dictionary

Tags: c#, image, dictionary, memory, loading

I've been doing some work with loading multiple image files into an HTML document that is then converted into a PDF.

I am unsure on the specifics, but I was under the impression it's better to read a single file at a time and keep the memory footprint low, rather than loading all the files into memory (in a dictionary) at once (there are so many images - the collection can be as big as 500MB!).

I was wondering what is faster though? Is it quicker to read say, 100MB worth of files into memory, process them, then load another 100MB? Or is it better to do it a single file at a time (surely the number of disk I/O operations would be similar in either regard)?

Comment: It is unlikely you'll notice a difference when the primary operation is so expensive.  Memory is fast, I/O is slow.  You ought to focus more on creating a program that can still work when those images take gigabytes.  Which is not unlikely.

Comment: Yeah that figures. I knew the IO operation would be slow, but there's no other way around it!

Answer (score 2):

It's better to read file one by one as it is more memory efficient. If you can you should work only with stream rather than in memory buffer.

When you use more memory, your data may ends in a [page file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) resulting in more disk I/O operations.

You should avoid working with large memory block if you don't want to see an  [OutOfMemoryException](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/).

Comment: Agreed, I've been in MemoryStream camp for this section of the development. Would it be better to load the image as a stream only, or to load it into a BitMap/Image and work from it there? I'm guessing direct-to-stream would be better

Comment: MemoryStream is a wrapper over an in memory buffer, not a 'true' stream. If you can, dont load image, use raw data (FileStream or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a number of things, but fundamentally, disk is a lot slower than memory, so you can gain by reading, if you do it right.

First, a warning: if you do not have plenty of memory to fit the files you attempt to load, then your operating system will page memory to disk, which will slow your system down far more than reading one file at a time, so be careful.

The key to improving disk io performance is to keep the disk busy.  Reading one at a time leaves the disk idle while you are processing the file in memory.  Reading a set of files into a large block of memory, but still reading one at a time, and then processing the block of files, probably won't improve performance except in very unusual conditions.

If your goal is to reduce the time from start to finish of processing these files, you will probably want to run on multiple threads; the system calls to open and read a file still take time to queue, so depending on the capabilities of your disk, you can usually get better overall io throughput by having at least one read request queued while the disk is loading another request; this minimizes idle time between requests, and keeps the disk at its absolute maximum.  Note that having too many requests queued can slow performance.

Since processing in memory is likely to be faster, you could have at least 2 threads set up to read files, and at least 1 thread set up to process the files that have already been loaded into memory by the other threads.

A better way than managing your own threads is to use a thread pool; this would naturally limit the number of io requests to the number of concurrent threads allowed, and wouldn't require you to manage the threads yourself.  This may not be quite optimal, but a thread pool should be faster than processing the files one at a time, and easier/safer than managing threads.

Note that if you don't understand what I mean by threads and a threadpool, or you haven't done much multi-threaded development relating to disk io, you are probably better off sticking with one file at a time, unless improving the total processing time is a requirement that you can't get around.  There are plenty of examples of how to use threads on MSDN, but if you haven't done it much, this probably isn't a good first project for threading.